# Firebase .childAdded does not work, because observed child might not exist yet

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use some data out of the Database for later purpose. However the data I want to load might not exist yet, because the observed data is a dictionary of friend requests which do not exist at the very first time the app is used. Although the .`childAdded` observer should do it, it just stops there and the code is not executed further

```
func getFriendRequest(_ uid: String, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    var friendRequests = [String]()
    let currentUserRef = DatabaseReference.users(uid: self.currentUser.uid).reference()
    currentUserRef.child("sendFriendRequest").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snap) in
        let request = FriendRequest(dictionary: snap.value as! [String : Any])
        let requestedUid = request.uid
        print(requestedUid)
        friendRequests = [requestedUid]
        completion(friendRequests)
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

It does not get into the observe method ...
Has anyone an idea why that is?

Answer (score 1):

The `.childAdded` completion handler will only be called when there is a child. If there are no child nodes it will not be invoked until you add a child under `sendFriendRequest`.